# Python "self" convention __init__ vs method

Tags: python

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.var = "hi"

   def some_method(self):
       print self.var

#for the example below
myClass= MyClass()
```

So I understand that the following statements are equivelent.

```
myClass.some_method()
MyClass.some_method(myClass)
```

It takes `object` and passes it as the first argument `self` to `some_method`.

But when I do :

```
myClass= MyClass()
```

How does this flow work?

I am assuming its slightly different, and some magic happens behind the scenes (someone has some memory to allocate).

How does that translate to `__init__(self)` ? What is passed  to `__init__` `MyClass` ?

Comment: Just a small nitpick: `object = MyClass()` redefines object, which is probably not what you want to do. :)

Comment: @mrb :) picky, picky (renamed object -> myClass)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`myClass= MyClass()` calls `MyClass.__new__` method to create an instance of `MyClass`. After that `MyClass.__init__` is called with this instance as first argument.

See the doc [`object.__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> object.`__new__`(cls[, ...])
>
> Called to create a new instance of class cls.
>
> object.`__init__`(self[, ...])
>
> Called when the instance is created.

Answer (score 3):

`__init__()` method is called immediately after an instance of the class is created.

[Dive into Python - Initializing and Coding Classes](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html#d0e11720)

Answer (score 2):

`MyClass()` creates a brand new object, which is passed to `__init__(self)` as the parameter `self`.  You can then set up whatever fields you want on `self`, and then `MyClass()` returns it.